# NullPointerException while using Butterknife

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

I am trying to *setText* a value to an *EditText* field. I have used ButterKnife to get ID of that EditText as:

```
@BindView(R.id.latitude_value)
TextView latitude_value;
@BindView(R.id.longitude_value)
TextView longitude_value;
@BindView(R.id.elevation_value)
TextView elevation_value;
```

And in onCreate, `ButterKnife.bind(this);`

however, when I try to setText to those TextView like :

```
 alertDialogBuilder
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setPositiveButton("Set",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                            String newlat = editText.getText().toString();
                            latitude_value.setText(newlat); //null pointer here
```

I get error :

```
java.lang.NullPointerException at PacakgeName.Household_Survey_Checklist$2.onClick(Household_Survey_Checklist.java:563)
```

What is happening?

*EDIT* : when I remove butterknife method of getting Ids and use 'findviewbyID', it works.

Comment: instead of `BindView` try `Bind`

Comment: Is the NPE at `String newlat = editText.getText().toString();` line? Is the `editText` defined somewhere?

Comment: I don't think Butterknife supports _Bind_ anymore @rookieDeveloper

Comment: yes @ShobhitPuri , editText is a field in AlertDialog from where value of new latitude comes.

Comment: Butterknife supports `Bind` and I think your issue is with `editText` try printing the value using Log you are getting from `editText`

Comment: Debug and find which is giving NPE "editext" or the "getText()" part. If edittext is null means there is something wrong with intialization and if getText() is null means the value you got as latitude is null

Comment: there is no problem with `editText` @rookieDeveloper . I'm getting the required value in Log. String `newlat` holds the value.

Comment: What  ? Then where are you getting NPE at ?. I thought you where getting NPE at this line `String newlat = editText.getText().toString();`

Comment: sorry, i'm getting the NPE in next line @sunilsunny : 

`latitude_value.setText(newlat)`

Comment: k .Please double check if `R.id.latitude_value` is in the correct layout itself. Is this an activity class. ?

Comment: yes it is @sunilsunny . i've checked it.

Comment: NPE is happening to `latitude_value` only or to all the 3 TextViews you given in question ? Also can you post the part of your gradle file where you are adding `butterKnife`.

Comment: Remember that in Java all code must be in a method inside a class. It will help a lot if you show this in your question. You should show the actual code of `onCreate()` and you should show the method which contains the `alertDialogBuilder` code. This gives us the context that helps us understand the order of execution of your code.

Comment: NPE is happening to all other fields @sunilsunny. But when I remove_ _Butterknife_ way of getting ID's and use traditional 'findviewByID' everything works fine.

Comment: Are you adding butterknife  like this in your gradle.. ?

     `compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.0.1'`
     `apt 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.0.1'`

Please post the relevant code.

Comment: Okay...I got it!
I didnt add the annotation processor dependency in my gradle file. It worked like a charm after I added this in my dependencies. It was very silly of me.
Thank you everyone for your efforts in helping me.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by adding annotationProcessor dependency in gradle file.

```
annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.4.0'
```